# RxAndroid FuncN compile/lint error

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I have a form with 14 fields that need to be valid before the submit button is enabled.

I have an observable on each of the fields, and I am using combineLatest() to make sure they are all valid at the same time.

I have tried it with smaller numbers of arguments, and it works well (when I use Func3, Func4, etc.).

The problem with combineLatest() is that when you are combining more than 9 observables, you must use FuncN as your combining observable. Here is a code example:

```
List <Observable<Boolean>> fieldObservables = new ArrayList<Observable<Boolean>>();

fieldObservables.add(field1Observable);
fieldObservables.add(field2Observable);
fieldObservables.add(field3Observable);
fieldObservables.add(field4Observable);
fieldObservables.add(field5Observable);
fieldObservables.add(field6Observable);
fieldObservables.add(field7Observable);
fieldObservables.add(field8Observable);
fieldObservables.add(field9Observable);
fieldObservables.add(field10Observable);
fieldObservables.add(field11Observable);
fieldObservables.add(field12Observable);
fieldObservables.add(field13Observable);
fieldObservables.add(field14Observable);

Subscription formReadySubscription = Observable
        .combineLatest(fieldObservables,
                new FuncN<Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public Boolean call(Boolean... readyArgs) {
                        for (Boolean ready : readyArgs) {
                            if (!ready) {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                })

        .subscribe(new Observer<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Boolean formValid) {
                // TODO: enable submit button
            }
        });
```

The above code gives two errors on FuncN:

`"Anonymous is not abstract and does not override abstract method call(Object...) in FuncN"` and 
`"Method does not override or implement a method from a supertype"` for its call() method.

It appears that `FuncN<Boolean>`'s call() method is expecting a list of Object rather than Boolean. (I'm wondering if this is a bug. I'm suspicious because Func2 (as an example) is defined as `Func2<Boolean, Boolean, Boolean>`, where two of the Booleans are parameters, and one of the Booleans is the expected return from the call() method. Keeping this pattern, you would expect FuncN's declaration to be `FuncN<Boolean,Boolean>`.)

Has anyone successfully gotten FuncN to work, and if so, how did you do it? Thanks!

Comment: have you tried changing 

`public Boolean call(Boolean... readyArgs) {`

to `public Boolean call(Object... readyArgs) {`

and then casting the parameters to Booleans inside the method?

Comment: It compiles! Thanks. It's not quite working yet, but that could be a logic error. I'll let you know.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek It works well. If you want to put this as the answer, I will accept it.

Comment: I have run up against a limit of 16 Observables that can be combined. More than that causes an exception generated by RxAndroid. To get around it, you can combine observables (using combineLatest) before adding them to the combine. I have tested this and it works.

Comment: `FuncN` is fairly ugly and does not have a generic parameter. It only accepts `R call(Object... args)`, which sucks, as you have to cast them afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

`public Boolean call(Boolean... readyArgs) {`

to

```
public Boolean call(Object... readyArgs) {
```

and then cast the parameters to Booleans inside the method